# Flutter how fixed entries in list

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to get data from firebase document and fill it in a list.
Get data from firebase document work. The list is filled.
But if i fill more than one list, the list are different.

See my db document:
[image]

Here is my list in visual studio code:

1. List:

```
I/flutter ( 5143): list: {eco_shipping: false, fairtrade: false, business_status: private, sub_category: null, status_color: 0, description: D, adress: A, delivery_time: 0, stars: 0, title: T, sell_status: search, eco: false, hashTags: [], user_id: YpPfU7cyAzLrS2sOtsRn4fXPIvV2, price: 0,02 €, main_category: Electronics, id: id_1631823807583_YpPfU7cyAzLrS2sOtsRn4fXPIvV2, create_date: Timestamp(seconds=1631823807, nanoseconds=0)}
```

2. List:

```
I/flutter ( 5143): list: {eco_shipping: false, business_status: private, fairtrade: false, sub_category: null, status_color: 0, description: D, adress: A, stars: 0, delivery_time: 0, title: T, sell_status: search, eco: false, hashTags: [], user_id: YpPfU7cyAzLrS2sOtsRn4fXPIvV2, price: 0,02 €, main_category: Electronics, id: id_1631824342677_YpPfU7cyAzLrS2sOtsRn4fXPIvV2, create_date: Timestamp(seconds=1631824342, nanoseconds=0)
```

My Problem:
I would fill the list in a object.
Object:

```
ProductDataObject(
          eco_shipping: list.entries.elementAt(0).value,
          fairtrade: list.entries.elementAt(1).value,
          business_status: list.entries.elementAt(2).value,
          sub_category: list.entries.elementAt(3).value,
          status_color: list.entries.elementAt(4).value,
          description: list.entries.elementAt(5).value,
          adress: list.entries.elementAt(6).value,
          stars: list.entries.elementAt(7).value,
          delivery_time: list.entries.elementAt(8).value,
          title: list.entries.elementAt(9).value,
          sell_status: list.entries.elementAt(10).value,
          eco: list.entries.elementAt(11).value,
          hashTag: list.entries.elementAt(12).value,
          user_id: list.entries.elementAt(13).value,
          price: list.entries.elementAt(14).value,
          main_category: list.entries.elementAt(15).value,
          product_id: list.entries.elementAt(16).value,
          create_date: list.entries.elementAt(17).value,
          image_url: [lst_image_url],
        ),
```

But for that i need always the same list series.

For example:

1. eco_shipping
2. fairtrade
3. business_status
4. sub_category ...

The example lists are not equals.
The entries fairtrade and business_status are not on the same index in my list.

My question:
How i can give the list a fix sequence (on entries)?
Many thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define this function in your `ProductDataObject` model

```
_productDatafromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  // I tried to infer your properties types from the data you gave, so
  // feel free to correct any type.
  return ProductDataObject(
    eco_shipping: json['eco_shipping'] as bool,
    fairtrade: json['fairtrade'] as bool,
    business_status: json['business_status'] as String,
    sub_category: json['sub_category'] as bool,
    status_color: json['status_color'] as int,
    description: json['description'] as String,
    adress: json['adress'] as String,
    stars: json['stars'] as int,
    delivery_time: json['delivery_time'] as String,
    title: json['title'] as String,
    sell_status: json['sell_status'] as String,
    eco: json['eco'] as bool,
    hashTag: (json['hashTag'] as List)?.map((e) => e as String)?.toList(),
    user_id: json['user_id'] as String,
    price: json['price'] as String,
    main_category: json['main_category'] as String,
    product_id: json['product_id'] as bool,
    // create_date type will be DateTime
    create_date: (json['create_date'] as Timestamp)?.toDate(),
    image_url: (json['image_url'] as List)?.map((e) => e as String)?.toList(),
  );
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
// for single ProductDataObject, use this
ProductDataObject data = _productDatafromJson(list);
print(data);

// for multiple ProductDataObject, use this:
List<Map<String, dynamic>> list; 
// here list is a List of Map<String, dynamic>. It is not a single Map<String, dynamic>
List<ProductDataObject> data = list.map((e) => _productDatafromJson(e)).toList();
print(data);
```

Comment: Hello Peter, thx for your answer. You help me alot. Now it's work. Here my solution 'eco_shipping: list.entries
              .where((element) => element.key == 'eco_shipping')
              .map((e) => e.value)
              .elementAt(0),'. Many thx (:

Comment: So glad I could help.